# Cloudflare 'direct' subdomain shows main site on IP address

Tags: dns, ip, subdomain, virtualhost, cloudflare

At the moment I'm hosting several websites under the same IP address, all running perfectly fine. Now I've added Cloudflare in front of them and for all websites, the subdomain `direct.`, points to the main website's main page.

Example setup of domain, if IP is `78.12.23.234`:

```
masterdomain.com
otherdomain.com
somedomain.com

direct.masterdomain.com → Master Domain website
direct.otherdomain.com → Master Domain website
direct.somedomain.com → Master Domain website
```

I've tried adding an alias to the website in question, but no success.
Is there an error in my setup of domains or should i change something on the Cloudflare side?

Answer (score 0):

It is only going to work against the root domain that is on us (masterdomain.com), if what I'm reading this correctly. That's what the A record is pointing to & what direct is working against (my assumption is the other sites are not on us individually).

Comment: I have all other websites also configured as independent website on CloudFlare with their own DNS settings as well. The only thing they have in common on DNS config is that they all point to the same IP. So theoretically it should be treated as their own `direct.` subdomain.

Comment: So are you saying the same site appears in all 3 cases? IE you visit direct.a.com and it displays the same as direct.b.com which displays the same as direct.c.com which is the same as www.a.com? Sounds like virtual server config issue if so.